# APS (Forge) Viewer "Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension" error by changing a Revit model view/geometry

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit-api

We are using **Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension** in our viewer for Revit models. But after changing a Revit view (or geometry) it throws errors.

This is how we implement LevelsExtension:

```js
const initViewer = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
            api: 'derivativeV2_EU',
            getAccessToken,
        };

        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
            const config = {
                extensions: [
                    'Autodesk.DocumentBrowser',
                    'Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension',
                ],
            };

            const container = document.getElementById('viewer');

            const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(
                container,
                config
            );

            viewer.start();

            resolve(viewer);
        });
    });
};

const loadModel = (viewer, model, index) => {
    const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (doc) => {
        const geometries = doc.getRoot().search({ type: 'geometry' });

        doc.downloadAecModelData();

        viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, geometries[index], {
            createWireframe: false,
            applyScaling: 'm',
            isAEC: true,
        });
    };

    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
        'urn:' + model.urn,
        onDocumentLoadSuccess,
        onDocumentLoadFailure
    );
};
```

As you can see before changing the view, there is a `div` for Levels panel with `id="LevelsPanel-0"`:
[image]

But after changing the view, there will be added another one without terminating the previous panel (as you can see the previous panel is still open):
[image]

And if you hover the previous open panel it will throw these errors:
[image]

Comment: There is no issue on your `initViewer` and `loadModel ` functions, but It would depend on how you unload and load the new model.

Comment: Actually I don't unload the previous model. I just call `loadModel` function again and pass the index of the geometry I want to see. Should I unload the previous one to avoid this issue? and how can I unload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your details. I can reproduce this issue even without using your code. I reported to our engineering team for insights. Our apologies for the inconvenience!

Here is a workaround that we remove the levelsPanel before loading the new model.

```js
viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension').levelsPanel?.setVisible(false);
viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension').levelsPanel?.container.remove();
```

#### Full code

```js
    const loadModel = (viewer, model, index) => {
      const onDocumentLoadSuccess = async (doc) => {
        if (viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension')) {
          viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension').levelsPanel?.setVisible(false);
          viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension').levelsPanel?.container.remove();
        }
        
        const geometries = doc.getRoot().search({ type: 'geometry' });

        doc.downloadAecModelData();

        viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, geometries[index], {
          createWireframe: false,
          applyScaling: 'm',
          isAEC: true,
        });
      };

      onDocumentLoadFailure = (error) => console.error(error);

      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
        'urn:' + model.urn,
        onDocumentLoadSuccess,
        onDocumentLoadFailure
      );
    };
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It works without error now. Thanks a lot Eason.